# Index is not working IE11

Tags: javascript

When i used to get object from

```
form.querySelector('[name="' + fieldName[i] + '"]'
```

it working fine but if i used

```
form.querySelector('[name="' + fieldName[i] + '"]')[index])
```

that added Index then it is not get object in IE11 browser is there any other way to get Index in IE11

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector` only returns the first matching element. What you want to use instead is `document.querySelectorAll`, which returns a list of matching elements. Note that this behavior is not specific to IE 11; the standards specify that only one value is returned from `document.querySelector`.

Comment: Ohhh Great thanks